# Power button won't shut down! it sleeps! (Samsung Chronos series 7, Win 7)

Tags: windows-7

I am having some trouble with power button. Even though I set it to shutdown action on start menu properties it gets the laptop in sleep mode when pressed.

I think this could be due to Samsung Easy Settings for my Samsung Series 7 laptop as for in last update they took off shutdown action option to the power button (just sleep / fast-on-mode / ask-when-I-press-button (which is what I have set but it actually never asks but goes to Sleep directly).

ps: Samsung Easy Settings (lousy but somehow useful app) is a quicker way to access laptop settings, therefore shutdown button acion and closed/open lid action, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to Control Panel → Power Option → Choose what the power button does
2. Go to change plan settings (of your currently selected plan) →  change advanced power settings → power buttons and lid → and there you can also select shut down

I think 2 is mostly for the physical button but if I remember correctly I needed to do both for the start menu button to work correctly (not sure it's been a while)

Also my Windows is not in English so some menu names might not be 100 % correct

Comment: thank you very much. Now It works, I didn't thought about it.